# What are the implications of calling vector::size / map::size in a non-thread-safe manner?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

As far as I can tell, `map::size` and `vector::size`, while `const` are not guaranteed thread-safe. One implementation of `vector` I found looks like this:

```
size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT
        {return static_cast<size_type>(this->__end_ - this->__begin_);}
```

If I call this method in a non-thread-safe way, what could go wrong? Simply that the result returned could be a few ms out of date, or could it could break other threads' attempts to modify the collection or otherwise risk serious problems?

Comment: thread safety is (unfortunately) not about return values being a bit out of date.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 well that depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What could go wrong?
Adding elements to the vector may cause reallocation and invalidate all iterators. If between your query to `begin` and `end` a reallocation happens, their difference will be gibberish.

Comment: Yes, also pointer updates are not guaranteed to be atomic, even if we `reserve` enough to never do reallocations, there is still potential for UB. Just one specific example of what could go wrong to help imagine what UB can look like (`size` returning crazy numbers). But UB is undefined, if the computer grows a leg and kicks you in the shin, that is still valid behavior for this code.

Answer (score 5):

> If I call this method in a non-thread-safe way, what could go wrong?

If the vector is being modified in another thread without synchronisation, then the behaviour of the program will be undefined. Anything could happen.